# How to redirect to a different domain using Nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx, vhosts

How can I redirect `mydomain.example` and any subdomain `*.mydomain.example` to `www.adifferentdomain.example` using Nginx?

Answer (score 382, accepted):

[server_name](http://nginx.org/r/server_name) supports suffix matches using `.mydomain.example` syntax:

```
server {
  server_name .mydomain.example;
  rewrite ^ http://www.adifferentdomain.example$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

or on any version 0.9.1 or higher:

```
server {
  server_name .mydomain.example;
  return 301 http://www.adifferentdomain.example$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Do I not need to put in a port to listen on? e.g. listen 80. I have multiple domains that I need to redirect to a primary domain, but my server also has multiple virtual servers for various other domains.

Comment: @Ryan The `listen` directive defaults to port 80 when not specified. It's actually a little more complicated than that in general; see the [nginx configuration docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Directives) for more details.

Comment: What does the `?` achieve at the end?

Comment: What's the difference between `rewrite` and `return 301 $scheme://www.adifferentdomain.com$request_uri;` ?

Comment: The ? at the end of a rewrite tells nginx not to append the original query string.  Since `$request_uri` already has the query string, there's no need to append it again.  The `return 301` syntax is newer, and there should be no difference in behavior between the two methods, but when I originally answered this question, many distributions didn't have the required version, so I went with the safer syntax.

Comment: Is it possible to forward matched subdomains? like redirect `site.com` to `site.org`, `www.site.com` to `www.site.org` and `test.site.com` to `test.site.org`?

Comment: For the `return 301` option, I do need a question mark at the end? Also, will `http://www.adifferentdomain.com$request_uri` include the variations of the `adifferentdomain` that do not include "www"?

Comment: @kolbyjack can you have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709219/ngnix-always-listening-to-port-80-by-default)

Comment: Nice answer. I used this technique for creating an SEO redirect from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com.

Comment: Since I had a bunch of ssl vhosts on the machine I had to add `listen 443 ssl;` for this to work instead of just pointing to the first returned vhost under a misleading domain.

Comment: For those who don't what the redirect be permanent, should use `302` code. A `301` redirect means that the page has permanently moved to a new location, while `302` redirect means that the move is only temporary.

Comment: will this work for web pages server or also for backend servers? I mean because the status code ```301 | 302```

Comment: seems that the https version (port 443) is not redirecting. any ideas?

Comment: note, that `return 301` is not working properly with any request method rather than GET. Most of the clients after getting redirecting response make a new request with GET, but not with an original method.

Answer (score 34):

```
server {
    server_name .mydomain.example;
    return 301 http://www.adifferentdomain.example$request_uri;
}
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#return

and

http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites

Answer (score 23):

I'm using this code for my sites

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443;
        server_name  .domain.example;

        return 301 $scheme://newdomain.example$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: This is the most accurate answer so far. `$scheme` might a bit debatable, but on the other hand it covers local dev/private networks cases.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Answer (score 20):

Why use the rewrite module if you can do `return`? Technically speaking, `return` is part of the rewrite module as [you can read here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#return) but this snippet is easier to read imho.

```
server {
    server_name  .domain.com;

    return 302 $scheme://forwarded-domain.com;
}
```

You can also give it a 301 redirect.

Comment: Will this keep the path and query params as well?

Comment: No this example does not do that @Mark. But I suppose you can mix up the previous answers to come up with something like this: `return 302 $scheme://forwarded-domain.com$request_uri;`

Comment: On a side note, in many cases, you should probably just redirect to https instead of preserving the scheme (ie use https instead of $scheme). This is for the same reasons protocol-relative links are now considered deprecated -  http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: @mahemoff That's not entirely true. Consider the case of having the webserver behind a loadbalancer that's discharging ssl.

Answer (score 13):

That should work via [HTTPRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule).

Example rewrite from `www.example.com` to example.com:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: that's just redirecting www.example.com to example.com. I want to redirect both to a different domain. Can I do that in one rule?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think that

server_name mydomain.com; rewrite www.adifferentdomain.com permanent; }

should do it?
That should take everything *.mydomain.com?

Comment: @deb you would just have `server_name example.com www.example.com;`.

Comment: The question specifically asks for *any subdomains* to redirect to a *different* domain. This answer answers none of the two (explicitly).

Comment: this is missing the important 301 !

Answer (score 11):

If you would like to redirect requests for `domain1.example` to `domain2.example`, you could create a server block that looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.example;
    return 301 $scheme://domain2.example$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Someone may need to redirect https:// request also.
    `listen 443;`

Comment: @RafikFarhad `listen 443 ssl;`

Answer (score 6):

You can simply write a if condition inside server {} block:

```
server {

    if ($host = mydomain.example) {
        return 301 http://www.adifferentdomain.example;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be careful using 'if' statements on Nginx ( https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ ). In this case you can just use 'server_name mydomain.com' instead.

Comment: if  is evil when used in location context, it is safe when used to specify redirect host

Answer (score 4):

**Temporary redirect**

```
rewrite ^ http://www.RedirectToThisDomain.example$request_uri? redirect;
```

**Permanent redirect**

```
rewrite ^ http://www.RedirectToThisDomain.example$request_uri? permanent;
```

**In Nginx configuration file for specific site:**

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite ^ http://www.RedictToThisDomain.example$request_uri? redirect;

}
```