# How to alias a localhost url to a remote-host url in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm using an Ubuntu 13.10 Server with LEMP stack. I have a Main server and a server that only has images stored on it. I want to point a local reference path: `images/folder_name/img.png` which would resolve as `http://www.server1.com/images/folder_name/img.png` to the same path but on a different directory `http://img.server2.com/images/differen_folder_name/img.png`.

Essentially, I want `http://www.server1.com/folder/img.png` to actually look up `http://www.server2.com/folder/img.png`.

Is there an NGINX configuration or something I can use to make this work?

Comment: Also, I may need help restructuring the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect to a different domain using NGINX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045020/how-to-redirect-to-a-different-domain-using-nginx)

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. I'd like to be able to point a specific URI to that of a different domain. Rewrite does seem to be a viable solution to the problem. I will update if I can get it working.