# NGINX - 301/Permanent redirects (*.cloudapp.azure.com to domain.com)

Tags: azure, redirect, nginx, dns, azure-virtual-network

i created an azure vps and redirected my domain to the dns . However i now have 2 domains pointing to my website which is not good for seo.

example.com

yyy..cloudapp.azure.com

I am using nginx web server and i want to permanently redirect all *.cloudapp.azure.com  to domain.com

I tried :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yyy.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com www.yyy.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com; 
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    server_name domain.com www.example.com;
    .....

}
```

It is not working . I restarted nginx server eaach time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) supports suffix matches using `.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com` syntax.

Try below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com; 
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Also, you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045020/how-to-redirect-to-a-different-domain-using-nginx) on SO.

Comment: @Sam.tuver I modify the configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. It works me fine.

Comment: When you access your web `yyy.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com` the url rewrite to `http://www.example.com`?

Comment: Thanks its working now . However when i use : yyy.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/page3 . It works instead of redirecting to the new site . How to fix this ?

Comment: @Sam.tuver  Maybe this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx#example-1-—-moving-to-a-different-domain) is helpful.