# Nginx redirect to another domain and append new parameter

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect all traffic from my `www.old-domain.com` to `www.new-domain.com`, while keeping all path and query parameters in the url, and append a new query parameter such as `&from-old=true`.

For example

```
www.old-domain.com --> www.new-domain.com/?from-old=true
www.old-domain.com/home --> www.new-domain.com/home?from-old=true
www.old-domain.com/item?id=123 --> www.new-domain.com/item?id=123&from-old=true
```

Please share some thoughts about how I should rewrite/return the url in Nginx to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045020/how-to-redirect-to-a-different-domain-using-nginx