# How to keep host when proxy to other servers in nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

For example. User request `http://user.dist.com`, the request will firstly arrived at nginx server,

```
upstream a.hello.com {
     server 10.243.26.104:8800;
 }
 server
  {
    listen 80;
    server_name user.dist.com;
    location /
    {
      proxy_pass http://a.hello.com;
    }
  }
```

and the server `a.hello.com` is running at `Node.js`, the Node sever want to get the real origin request host which should be `user.dist.com`, but now, the Node server get `a.hello.com`, so how to get the origin host?

Comment: can u please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045020/how-to-redirect-to-a-different-domain-using-nginx

its help you to how to redirect to other domain

Answer (score 0):

you can use proxy_set_header-

```
proxy_set_header HOST $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```