# Using Nginx server block 301 redirect but domain not redirecting

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, redirect

**What I've tried:**

I've implemented a 301 redirect from an old domain to the new domain being used on a site after following this: [How to redirect to a different domain using NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045020/how-to-redirect-to-a-different-domain-using-nginx)

**What is happening:**

The domain is still not redirecting though, and it's been over 24 hours.

What happens is that an SSL warning comes up when I go to the old domain, and after clicking "continue to website" I go through to the new website (new changes I've made, stored in /var/www/new_domain/html), but with the old domain.

**Request:**

Where should I start troubleshooting this?  I need to redirect this domain for SEO transference.

**Code:**

This is the nginx server block of the old domain:

```
server {

    root /var/www/old_domain_webroot_dir/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html;

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name old_domain.com www.old_domain.com;
    rewrite 301 https://new-domain.com$request_uri;
```

}

Comment: what's warning ？

Comment: @MattiaDinosaur I get an ssl warning like "this site is not safe..", then when I click continue I come to the website with all new additions, except its using the old domain not redirecting to the new one

Comment: The syntax is wrong for the `rewrite` directive. I think you meant to use `return 301 ...`.