# how redirect domain from nginx to another domain which is working on same nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

i have a server droplet in Digital ocean , two domains pointing out to that server A.com and B.com . i want that when A.Com is call then nginx redirect it to B.com and server as B.com . e.g if user hit url from browser B.com then my site should be shown but if it Hit A.com then same site should be open but domain changes to B.com

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41503835/4862445) answer your question?

Comment: @RichardSmith its not for my problem

Answer (score 5):

This is some example how to do it:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  a.com;
    location / {
      return 301 $scheme://b.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't we use the proxy_pass instead of return? can you please help me understand that?

Comment: Because `proxy_pass` will use more resources on the server because the data will come through nginX twice. With `return` the connection is closed and the browser is adviced to open a new connection to the new domain.

Answer (score 2):

Add this server block

This is to redirect

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com; // your domain name
   location / {
          return 301 https://redirect-to.com; //Add your redirect url here
   }
}
```