# Return is not working as redirector, and proxy_pass fails on relative path

Tags: nginx, redirect

I need classic "URL redirect" and, supposing that [`location return` is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60205890/287948), I used:

```
        location ~ ^/?[RrWwNn]?[0-9]+$ {
                rewrite
                  ^/?[Rr]?([0-9]+)$
                  /relation/$1
                  break;
                rewrite
                  ^/?[Ww]?([0-9]+)$
                  /way/$1
                  break;
                rewrite
                  ^/?[Nn]?([0-9]+)$
                  /node/$1
                  break;
                # proxy_pass  https://www.openstreetmap.org;
                return 301 https://www.openstreetmap.org;
        }
```

But it returns **`404 Not Found`**.

---

#### Note about commented proxy_pass

It is not a URL or a rewrite problem, because `proxy_pass` is working as expected. The problem on preserving my domain is the *relative path* on OpenStreetMap's HTML (`src` and `href` attributes), that demands files that not exists on my domain. Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
...
  <script src="/assets/application-2b1976907d32c6d0274def6df7df5970c274bc239f2cbd39ab43bd94cb828407.js"></script>
...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/screen-ltr-dccece0ade0dcdf51378c9d06264575b38c6bb23351144314efde0956d6883cf.css" media="screen" />
...
```

Comment: You cannot use `return` like a `proxy_pass`. The `rewrite` and `return` are both from the [rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) and `break` stops all module processing. You should use `rewrite ^/?[Rr]?([0-9]+)$ https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/$1 permanent;` instead (if I understand your requirements correctly).

Comment: Your suggestion `rewrite regex URL permanent`  is working, thanks @RichardSmith!